# why safe update mode block me while i use a where that include key colums in update join sql in mysql

Tags: mysql

i run a update join sql in mysql, below is my sql

```
UPDATE a
        JOIN
    b ON a.id = b.pid 
SET 
    a.t = b.name
WHERE
    a.id > 0 AND b.id > 0
```

then i got error:

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.
```

the id in both table is the primary key. i just confuse why i am using the where that include the key column, mysql still block me. i know turn off the safe update mode can work(but it's not a good practice), so i want to understand what is the problem about my sql, and how to correct it. i am very curious about the reason.thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe the optimizer is clever enough to filter out that condition. Try `where 1 = 1`

Comment: This seems to be some kind of maintenance query (right?) Just temporarily `SET sql_safe_updates=0`, do your update, and then set it back to 1

Comment: @juergend i try it, but doesn't work.

Comment: @Cid yes i know it, it confuse me, so i just want to know reason. why i get block while use a where include primary column